# Why do I need to go through edit model in Gazebo in order for my model to spawn correctly?

Tags: gazebo, robot, model

When I initially launch my robot in Gazebo, it breaks apart and every part is moving around.

[image]

As soon as I enter edit mode for my model it freezes in place, and then I can delete and launch the model again and it'll be in the correct orientation without shaking or breaking apart.

[image]

How do I prevent my model from shaking and breaking apart outside of going through the edit model every time I wish to load my model into Gazebo?

Comment: Are you using position control, and does your gripper extend below the "floor" to negative values of the z coordinate? Can you move the robot properly after you exit edit mode?

Comment: @danzimmerman, Yes the gripper does extend below the floor. I tried taking this https://foxglove.dev/blog/simulating-robotic-scenarios-with-ros1-and-gazebo simulation and adjusting it to my needs. About trying to move the robot, I'm not sure, I wanted to try to solve my model problems before I start trying to control it, but maybe that's not feasible. 
I should note, that this happens even when I only use a partial model, and all the pieces are above ground.